# Is xively activation necessary

Tags: activation, xively

Why does xively accept data for a device even if it is not activated. Is activation really necessary as I can view the data that is uploaded to a non activated device in any case.

Answer (score 0):

Activation is not necessary, especially if you are using a "Development Device". The activation process is designed for companies which wish to have a large number of Xively devices without having to manually enter a Feed ID and API key on every device. The provisioning (activation) process allows you to have the same firmware load on every device while still being able to give unique credentials to every device.

The one caveat is that the device must have a unique identifier of some kind, serial number, MAC address, could be anything really.

Answer (score -1):

My devices are not in development phase, but in management phase. Even so they do not require to be activated for the xively server to accept and log data. Is this expected?